# ember loading route on fetching data

Tags: ember.js

Is there any opportunity to trigger loading route whenever data is fetching?

```
RM.Public.ItemsController = RM.ApplicationController.extend({
...snip...
  pageContent: ->
    @set 'newItems',
      RM.Blurb.find({search_conditions:@get('search_conditions')})
})
```

In ember LoadingRoute triggers whenever model receives data.

```
RM.Public.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
...snip...
  setupController:(controller, model) ->
    controller = @controllerFor('public/items')
    controller.set("model", model)

  model: ->
    RM.Item.find({}).then( (modelData) ->
      modelData
    )
)
```

But in this case loading route will triggered only once.

Here is life example of LoadingRoute in action
http://jsbin.com/ANERoRi/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading route only triggers when Ember is transitioning from one route to another and Ember is  waiting on model returned from the model hooks to resolve.  That being said the easiest thing for you to do would be to hook into the document's ajax triggers and manually pop up some html.  Here's a mini library, you start it by calling `AjaxNotice.initializeGlobalEvents();` once (probably in your application route, or didInsertElement of your application view.

```
var AjaxNotice = {

  initializeGlobalEvents: function () {
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
      AjaxNotice.addAjaxNotice();
    });

    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
      AjaxNotice.removeAjaxNotice();
    });
  },

  addAjaxNotice: function () {
    AjaxNotice.slideInNotice();
  },

  removeAjaxNotice: function () {
    AjaxNotice.slideOutNotice();
  },

  slideInNotice: function () {
    $('body').append(AjaxNotice.getHtml());
  },

  slideOutNotice: function () {
   $("#ajax_notice").remove();
  },

  getHtml: function () {
    return '<div id="ajax_notice" class="ajax_spinner"> Working...</div>'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Daniel!
How do you think , will Loading Route trigger if i will redirect from pagination/1 , to the pagination/2 (pagination/:N)?

Comment: Yes it should (as long as you don't already have the models).  The loading route is currently undergoing a face lift, so if it doesn't appear to work and you are using a newer version you should be cognizant of a breaking change. http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-nested-loading-routes/2895

Comment: Thank you for this one!
Comment as useful as the answer.